# achartengine draw axis without data?

Tags: android, achartengine

It is possible to draw only x and y axis without data? (because in my app I must draw line after 5sec). I set min and max values for axis, but without any data graph doesn't want redraw.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add empty Arraylist to dataset.

Answer (score 0):

What toni means, is adding and empty data series to the dataset, i.e. something like this:

```
GraphicalView mChartView;
XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(new XYSeriesRenderer());
mDataset.addSeries(new XYSeries("some name"));
```

However, in that case there are only graph lines without labels, ticks, grid, etc. Only after I add one (at least) data point these things show up to form a proper graph:

```
mXYSeries.add(0, 0);
```

This additional series has to be deleted right after you get real data because it shows up in the legend and produce other unwanted side effects. Unfortunately I don't know any better way of creating the axis lines with AChartEngine without data.